# How to kill a process which is running form a directory in CentOS?

Tags: java, linux, shell, apache-spark, centos

We have a requirement where we have copies of the same Spark application (basically a .jar file) running from different folders. I am looking for a shell command using which I can kill the Spark app running in one folder without killing other spark jobs.

Ex:

> ```
> /home/user/Folder1 - CapStoneSpark.jar
> /home/user/Folder2 - CapStoneSpark.jar
> /home/user/Folder3 - CapStoneSpark.jar
> ```

The main class in the jar file is "CapStoneSparkMain". Suppose, I want to kill the CapStoneSpark.jar running in Folder2 only without touching or killing the CapStoneSpark.jar running from Folder1 and Folder3, then what should I do?

I have already tried:

```
kill $(ps aux | grep 'CapStoneSparkMain' | awk '{print $2}')
```

But, it kills all the process which have "CapStoneSparkMain" class in them.

I only want to kill the process originating from a single directory and don't want to touch the copies of the processes running from other directories.

Comment: The lsof command may help you identify the correct pid to kill

Comment: I am new to shell scripting. Could you please guide me on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all Proccess ID's which using these folders:

```
lsof | grep /home/user/Folder | awk '{print "kill " $2}'
```

And execute it:

```
lsof | grep /home/user/Folder | awk '{print "kill " $2}'|sh
```

Comment: I think OP only wants to kill CapStone processes.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how the jobs are started, but assuming that each job is started with a different working direectory, it is possible kill the specific job. Given that it's possible to find the working directory of each process via the /proc/$$/cwd (symlink to the job folder). Building on the commands/loop suggested above:

```
kill_folder=/home/user/Folder2
for pp in $(ps aux | grep 'CapStoneSparkMain' | awk '{print $2}') ; do
    if [[ /proc/$$/cwd -ef "$kill_folder" ]]  && kill $$
done
```

The code will check if the symlink /proc/$$/cwd matches the named folder (kill_folder), and will only issue the kill to processes in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

#### Hello

A for loop that check for the user in...

```
for i in $(pidof application); do grep -o ${user} /proc/${i}/cmdline; done
```

And `if` it fits your desire `then` put `kill` command on `${i}` in loop.